# What is the area very deep meaning?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, area

For example,

Why we say :

> If one side of the square is $a$ then $a^2$ is the area of the square.

What is the meaning of area in complex space?

Can you explain academically, this meaning?

Comment: yep ,-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1 ,without thinking, because We used to "ax=b" etc.

Comment: Are you asking about a square in the complex plane?

Comment: yes this  and , how they did formulize  "If one side of the square is $a$ then $a^2$ is the area of the square." how we so sure about this.

Comment: One way to formalize the notion of area is using 2-dimensional Lebesgue measure. There is an isometry between $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$, namely the map $a+bi \mapsto (a,b)$, so any square in the complex plane can be equivalently viewed as a square in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and its area computed using 2-dimensional Lebesgue measure.

Comment: It's easy if $a$ is a whole number; just break the big square into a bunch of smaller squares of side-length $1$. Rational side lengths aren't much harder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the most basic level, area is a function that takes as input a subset of the plane, and as output returns a non-negative real number. Furthermore, any candidate for an "area function" should add properly, in the sense that the area of the union of disjoint sets is the sum of the areas.

It seems reasonable to require that area be translation invariant - that is, if you take a shape and simply translate it from one place to another without changing it otherwise, then the area should stay the same.

With these simple principles, it is already determined that an $n$-by-$n$ square has $n^2$ times as much area as a $1$-by-$1$ square, since you can build an $n$-by-$n$ square out of $n^2$ "tiled" $1$-by-$1$ squares via translation.

You can show that the side-squared formula holds for fractional and rational side lengths via similar tiling constructions, and then extend it to irrational side lengths by "squeezing" the square between inner and outer approximations.

This sort of axiomatic construction of area from simple principles is studied in great detail in the subject of [measure theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_%28mathematics%29) (and in particular, Haar measures), which is a fascinating topic worth looking into, if you want to understand this stuff deeply.